# Angular2 Bootstrap in multipage application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-bootstrap

I have a multipage non-angular application where Angular2 is used in only one page. I am appending root component using javascript and angular2 gets properly bootstraped for the first time.

However, when I go to other non-angular pages and comeback to my angular2 page, there is some issue with the bootstrapping as it only shows **loading...** which is static text in my root component.

Comment: Do you have any output in your browser console?

Comment: Nothing. None of the component code is getting executed.